# Trying to find a font to match a logo

Tags: critique, font-recommendation

As part of my college project, I have chosen a well known local design company and I am redoing their logo, as you can see I have got quite far with the logo however I am having trouble finding a font to suit. I have tried dafont and 1001 free fonts and many other sites but I just cant seem to find a font that matches the beginning letters of each word. This is now the last resort as I cant seem to find one :(. Oh and I would prefer a free one! hehe

[image: unfinished logo so far]

---

Update:

This is what the final piece was. Thanks for everybody that has helped. Its lovely to have somewhere to go to bounce ideas off of people as nobody I know or talk to are designers.

Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: Looks like ObGyn logo, I'm sorry

Comment: I would have started in the other end - first create the text and then use parts of it to create the icon. On the other hand - it seems like a case of "can't kill my darling". You have to consider the option of redoing the icon if you can't get it to work as you want to. It's a part of this job, which you'll notice when you get a job in the business.

Comment: This very much is a can't kill her situation, she has taken me a long time to develop :(

Comment: and I never saw that until now @Ilan... your bad!

Comment: I'd suggest to remove gradients - they will distract you while resizing, and they also outdated. Secondly, these areas are problematic IMHO http://i.stack.imgur.com/nBCNB.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO (!)

I would leave only first element (left one) and it central part I'd increase and probably rotate (as well as external one).

The modern look - I'd create by adding airy light font like on the image I've just created -

[image]

Comment: thats a fair comment man and I see your point, Ill try it, my only worry is that doing that there isnt the connection with the CDC... would that not just make the whole thing pointless? lol

Comment: I like the lighter font weight. I agree with the CDC getting a little lost, though, especially because according to the OP's idea this would currently be read as "CDCD" or "CCDD". Also, unrelated but when I saw the first logo I also instantly thought of ObGyn :/

Comment: @DanielNolan You can play with shapes as you want, but remember - If you make a logo which is read as text below it... you create tautology. I've just gave my points - you still should work yourself :)

Comment: @Ilan your input has really helped and made me think, so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a very small chance that you'll find a typeface that'll match the logo you created. I understand that you want to repeat the letters from the logo in the type to 'explain' the logo. I think you only have two alternatives:

1. Set the entire text in the same type, even the initials. Pity, but no 'explanation', the viewer will have to figure out on her own what's going on.
2. Design the 'entire' typeface, or at least, design the letters you'd need to spell out the company name. That way you ensure the connection between the image and the type, without any inevitable 'clash' between your type and another.

Comment: do you think its good enough that they will 'figure it out' thanks man

Comment: It depends. Do you think viewers are [geniuses](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ViewersAreGeniuses) or [morons](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ViewersAreMorons)?

Answer (score 2):

This is just an opinion:

Separate typeface and logo makes for a much easier path to success.

Consider these iconic logos that stood the test of time, they don't tend to incorporate type into logos:

Nike, NBC, Apple, McDonalds, Target, Pepsi, American Airlines

If you really want to use type face as a logo consider using a homogeneous approach where all of the type face is the SAME typeface:

Coca-Cola, Disney, IBM, VW, etc.

Either of those solutions would be a lot easier than making two different typefaces flow within a single word.